# overloading methods problems

Tags: java, methods

i know im doing this completely wrong atm, im new to coding and i know whatever im doing is wrong. Just trying though.

Create two overload methods which return the average of an array of numbers. one method is

```
public static double average (int[] array)
```

other method header is

```
public static double average (double[] array)
```

My main method i want to invoke both of these, and print the average. First array using {1,2,3,4,5} to test the average method that accepts integers and this array {6.0,5.0,4.0,3.0,2.0,1.0} to test the average method that accepts doubles as a parameter.

now my code, is probably looking aweful. I really dont know.

```
public class methodss 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        //invoke the average int method
        System.out.println("Average with int: " + average);
        //invoke the average double method
        System.out.println("Average with double: " + average);

        public static double average (int[] array)
        {
            int sum = 0, average = 0;

            array[5] = {1,2,3,4,5}
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i){
                sum+=array[i];
                average = sum/5;
                return average;
            }
        }

        public static double average (double[] array)
        {
            int sum = 0, average2 = 0;

            array[6] = {6.0, 5.0, 4.0, 3.0, 2.0, 1.0};
            for (int x = 0; x < 10; ++x){
                sum+=array[x];
                average = sum/6;
                return average;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you could do methodss.average(new int[0]) and methodss.average(new double[0]);

Comment: If you know that you doing it completely wrong then stop and learn the right way to do it.

Answer (score 2):

Try this instead,

```
// Classes normally are named like proper nouns, so they start with a captial letter
public class Methods 
{
    // main is the entry point of the app.
    // all the args that are entered on the command line are passed in
    // as an array of strings.
    // the keyword static here means that this method belongs to this class
    // so all invokations are in terms of the class.
    // i.e. java Methods ... implicitly invokes Methods.main()
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        //invoke the average int method
            System.out.println("Average with int: " + Methods.average(1, 2, 3, 4, 5));
        //invoke the average double method
            System.out.println("Average with double: " + Methods.average(1.0, 5.4, 2.3, 1.6);
    }

        /**
        * takes the average of an arbitrary amount of primitive ints
        * @param array a varg of ints, so that the caller can specify calls
        *   to the method like average(1) or average(1, 2) or average(new int[10]),
        *   makes calling this function in adhoc ways readable.
        * @returns a double representing the average of all the elements in the arguments
        **/
        public static double average (int... array)
        {
            int sum = 0;
            double average = 0.0;
            // loop through the array and stop when the iterator int, i
            // reaches the amount of elements in the array.
            // the amount of elements in the array can be read by the
            // special instance variable on array types called length.
            for (int i = 0; i < array.length; ++i){
                sum += array[i];
            }
            // so that these don't get truncated, inserting a 1.0 to make sure it's
            // a double. Otherwise the average of (1, 2) would be 1 instead of 1.5
            average = 1.0 * sum/array.length;
            return average;
        }


        /**
         * Same as average(int...) but with doubles
         **/ 
        public static double average (double... array)
        {

            double sum = 0.0, average = 0.0;

            for (int x = 0; x < array.length; ++x){
                sum += array[x];
            }
            average = sum/array.length;
            return average;
        }
}
```

Comment: It looks like homework so I assume using `double... array` will definitely show that he hasn't done this on his own ;)

Comment: no homework is done on your own. Some read books, some read the internet ... and get this, some people actually ask questions. No one knows it out of the blue. If he wants to copy and paste without learning that's his problem :) It's still a valid question and a valid answer to that question.